# c++ comparator sorting using auxillary array

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda, stl

I have an array (say `values`) that that cannot be modified. I want to know if the values in this array are sorted what will be their eventual position/index. So, for this I am simply using code as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned> position(11, 0);
    std::iota(position.begin(), position.end(), 0);
    std::vector<unsigned> values = {140, 141, 118, 119, 122, 123, 128, 129, 133, 134, 138, 139};
    
    auto value_comparator = [&values](const unsigned& index1, const unsigned& index2) {
        return (values[index1] < values[index2]);
    };
    
    std::sort(position.begin(), position.end(), value_comparator);
    
    for (auto val : position) {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Actual Output**:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 0 1
```

**Expected Output**:

```
10 11 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I am trying to understand why the output is as shown above. Looks like STL uses `IntroSort`. Looking for some input before I dig deeper.

Thanks.

Comment: That looks pretty much like the right output to me, why would you expect e.g. the first indices to be `10` and `11`, where the associated values are `138` and `139`, which are not the lowest ones in `values`?!

Comment: @lubgr `10` and `11` shows that `140` sorted position is `10` and `141` sorted position is `11`.

Comment: @RachitAgrawal That's not what your code does. Your code sorts the second array is relation to the values in the first one. So `2` at index `0` shows that the value at position `2` in your second array is the first element when it's sorted.

Comment: What @super means is that your output shows the original index of the values.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Didn't realize that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sorts the indices by their value in the array. So the output will have at the first position the index of the smallest value, in the second the index of the second-smallest and so on.

To get what you want out of that, you can, for example, do the following:

```
std::vector<unsigned> result(position.size());
for(unsigned i = 0; i < position.size(); ++i) {
    result[position[i]] = i;
}
```